# ¿Como hacer que no me permita seleccionar otra fila cuando estoy editando una fila. en un DataTable?

Tags: java, netbeans, jsf, primefaces, java-ee

Quiero saber como hacer que no me permita seleccionar otra fila cuando estoy editando una fila.[[image] 
Esto es lo que pasa cuando edito una fila y si llego a dar check en la fila que edito no hace ningun cambió](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZHbL3.png)
[[image]Este es mi codigo estoy trabajando con ajax y he intentado de varias formas pero no encuentro una solución.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S3xcL.png)

Este es el datatable he tratado de evitar que nose seleccione pero solo logre borrar los iconos para la edición pero no evito que se seleccione les comparto mi codigo para que me puedan ayudar.

```
        <h:form id="DetalleInformacion_1ListForm">
                    <p:dataTable id="datalist" value="#{detalleInformacionController.items}" var="item"
                                 selection="#{detalleInformacionController.selected}"
                                 paginator="true"
                                 rowKey="#{item.IDDETINFO}"
                                 widgetVar="wdtDetalleInformacion"
                                 rowIndexVar="index" editable="true"
                                 sortBy="#{item.IDASIGCUL.IDCUL.TIPCUL}" expandableRowGroups="true"
                                 stickyHeader="true" stickyTopAt=".layout-topbar" selectionMode="single"
                                 lazy="true">

                        <p:ajax event="rowEditInit"
                                oncomplete="$('.ui-row-editor span.ui-icon-pencil').each(function(){$(this).hide()});" />

                        <p:ajax event="rowEdit" 
                                listener="#{detalleInformacionController.calcular()}"
                                update="datalist:VERDMES"
                                oncomplete="$('.ui-row-editor span.ui-icon-pencil').each(function(){$(this).show()});"/>   

                        <p:ajax event="rowEditCancel" 
                                onstart="$('.ui-row-editor span.ui-icon-pencil').each(function(){$(this).show()});"/>

                    <p:headerRow>
                        <p:column colspan="11">
                            <h:outputText value="#{item.IDASIGCUL.IDCUL.TIPCUL}" converter="C_TipoCultivo"/>
                        </p:column>
                    </p:headerRow>

                    <p:column headerText="Cultivo" filterBy="#{item.IDASIGCUL.IDCUL.NOMCUL}"  width="120">
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.IDASIGCUL.IDCUL.NOMCUL}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="Mes anterior" width="50">
                        <h:outputText value="#{item.VERMESANT}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="#{vistas.ListDetalleInformacion_1Title_credet}" width="50">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{item.CREDET}" rendered="#{item.CREDET > 0}"/></f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input"><p:spinner value="#{item.CREDET}"  min="0" max="9999.99" stepFactor="0.25"
                                                             rendered="#{item.IDASIGCUL.IDCUL.TIPCUL == 'PM'}"/></f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="#{vistas.ListDetalleInformacion_1Title_prodet}" width="50">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{item.PRODET}" rendered="#{item.PRODET > 0}"/></f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input"><p:spinner value="#{item.PRODET}" min="0" max="9999.99" stepFactor="0.25"
                                                             rendered="#{item.IDASIGCUL.IDCUL.TIPCUL  == 'PM'}"/></f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>

                    <p:column headerText="#{vistas.ListDetalleInformacion_1Title_semdet}" width="50">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{item.SEMDET}" rendered="#{item.SEMDET > 0}"/></f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input"><p:spinner value="#{item.SEMDET}" min="0" max="9999.99" stepFactor="0.25"
                                                             rendered="#{item.IDASIGCUL.IDCUL.TIPCUL  != 'PM'}"/></f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="#{vistas.ListDetalleInformacion_1Title_cosdet}" width="50">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{item.COSDET}" rendered="#{item.COSDET > 0}"/></f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input"><p:spinner value="#{item.COSDET}" min="0" max="9999.99" stepFactor="0.25"
                                                             rendered="#{item.IDASIGCUL.IDCUL.TIPCUL  != 'PM'}"/></f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="#{vistas.ListDetalleInformacion_1Title_afedet}" width="50">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{item.AFEDET}" rendered="#{item.AFEDET > 0}"/></f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input"><p:spinner value="#{item.AFEDET}" min="0" max="9999.99" stepFactor="0.25"
                                                             rendered="#{item.IDASIGCUL.IDCUL.TIPCUL  != 'PM'}"/></f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="#{vistas.ListDetalleInformacion_1Title_perdet}" width="50">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{item.PERDET}" rendered="#{item.PERDET > 0}"/></f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input"><p:spinner value="#{item.PERDET}" min="0" max="9999.99" stepFactor="0.25"
                                                             rendered="#{item.IDASIGCUL.IDCUL.TIPCUL  != 'PM'}"/></f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="#{vistas.ListDetalleInformacion_1Title_rotdet}" width="50">
                        <p:cellEditor>
                            <f:facet name="output"><h:outputText value="#{item.ROTDET}" rendered="#{item.ROTDET > 0}"/></f:facet>
                            <f:facet name="input"><p:spinner value="#{item.ROTDET}" min="0" max="9999.99" stepFactor="0.25"/></f:facet>
                        </p:cellEditor>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column headerText="#{vistas.ListDetalleInformacion_1Title_verdmes}" width="50">
                        <h:outputText id="VERDMES" value="#{item.VERDMES}"/>
                    </p:column>
                    <p:column style="width:15px">
                        <p:rowEditor />
                    </p:column>
                </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
```

Comment: Por favor, añade tu código en formato de texto

Comment: Acabo de agregar el codigo del XHTML.